# Capture controller name and method name using NLog in dotnet core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, nlog

I'm trying to capture controller name and method name in a dotnet core application using NLog library. Below set of codes are used in config to capture them. I'm able to get controller and action name, but not getting the expected result.

**Nlog Config file:**

```
 <targets>   
  <target xsi:type="File" archiveAboveSize="10000000" archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence" name="eventLog" fileName="D:\MiningApp\Logs\MiningApp_Log_${shortdate}.log"
    layout="${longdate} | ${uppercase:${level}} | ${callsite} | ${logger} | ${message}" />
 </targets>
```

**Current Result:**

```
2021-07-21 15:34:17.1299 | INFO | MiningApp.Controllers.MasterController.GetUsers | MiningApp.Controllers.MasterController | Logging started for department
2021-07-21 15:34:17.2165 | INFO | MiningApp.Controllers.MasterController+<GetUsers>d__42.MoveNext | MiningApp.Controllers.MasterController | Logging ended for department
```

**Expected Result:**

```
2021-07-21 15:34:17.1299 | INFO | ControllerName: MiningApp.Controllers.MasterController | MethodName : MiningApp.Controllers.MasterController.GetUsers | Logging started for department
2021-07-21 15:34:17.1376 | INFO | ControllerName: MiningApp.Controllers.MasterController | MethodName : MiningApp.Controllers.MasterController.GetUsers | Logging ended for department
```

Also I need to set file limit to 10MB and when the file reaches the size then it should create a new file. File names should be like `Ex: MiningApp_Log_21.07.2021_01, MiningApp_Log_21.07.2021_02`. Really appreciate any inputs or suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your expected result, this should work:

```
<targets>   
<target xsi:type="File" archiveAboveSize="10000000" archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence" name="eventLog" fileName="D:\MiningApp\Logs\MiningApp_Log_${shortdate}.log"
  layout="${longdate} | ${uppercase:${level}} | ControllerName: ${callsite:methodName=false} | MethodName: ${callsite:includeSourcePath=false} | ${message}" />
</targets>
```

Configured from reading the docs at: https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers

Comment: I still get two issues 1. This value is getting appended in the log `+<GetUsers>d__42 ` as you can see in the post. Also the file numbers are not getting created sequentially. It is created like this `MiningApp_Log_2021-07-21, MiningApp_Log_2021-07-21.20210721.0, MiningApp_Log_2021-07-21.20210721.1`. But I need something like `MiningApp_Log_2021-07-21_01, MiningApp_Log_2021-07-21_02`.

Comment: For your file numbers I don't have a solution for you, and for the value that is getting appended try tinkering with the configurations here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Callsite-Layout-Renderer I hope I helped